# Joining three tables and finding a sum of payments in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am struggling with this problem in MySQL. The question asks...

Find the names of the individuals and businesses that have made no more than three payments.

Individuals is a table, businesses is a table, and payments is a table. The problem I am having is Payments only contains columns dateFiled and amountPaid. I tried creating a count operation, but it shows blank results.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT Individuals.name, Businesses.name, Payments.taxpayerID, COUNT(*) AS 'Payments'
FROM Payments
JOIN Individuals ON Payments.taxpayerID=Individuals.taxpayerID
JOIN Businesses ON Payments.taxpayerID=Businesses.taxpayerID
GROUP BY Businesses.name, Individuals.name, Payments.taxpayerID
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3;
```

If anyone can help me solve this it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Don't join individuals and businesses if they're unrelated

Comment: Help us help you - please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it.

Comment: Use this [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/) to create db fiddle and someone can help you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess what you are looking for is not a join of three tables but a union of two selects:

```
SELECT Individuals.name, Payments.taxpayerID, COUNT(*) AS 'Payments'
FROM Payments 
JOIN Individuals ON Payments.taxpayerID=Individuals.taxpayerID
GROUP BY Individuals.name, Payments.taxpayerID
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3
UNION
SELECT Businesses.name, Payments.taxpayerID, COUNT(*) AS 'Payments'
FROM Payments
JOIN Businesses ON Payments.taxpayerID=Businesses.taxpayerID
GROUP BY Businesses.name, Payments.taxpayerID
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 3;
```

Your version is giving zero results, because a tax ID is either associated with a business or an individual. Therefore you need to query both independently and combine the results with union.

That said, yes you could work with joins and only a single select but then you'd need outer joins and the query would be less readable IMHO.

Comment: You're welcome. If it works and it is the answer you expected, then please mark the answer as accepted ;-)